# create a record with ROWTYPE and extra column

Tags: plsql

I want to create a RECORD type based on a table which also contain an extra column.
something like this:

```
type rec is record
(
  x urowid,
  test_exception%rowtype
);

inst_rec rec;
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to write all the fields of the test_exception table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to name the rowtype part:

```
type rec is record
(
  x urowid,
  te_rec test_exception%rowtype
);

inst_rec rec;
```

For example, using the EMP table:

```
declare
   type t_emp_plus_rec is record
      ( emprec emp%rowtype
      , extra integer
      );
   emp_plus_rec t_emp_plus_rec;
begin
   emp_plus_rec.emprec.empno := 123;
   emp_plus_rec.emprec.ename := 'SMITH';
   emp_plus_rec.extra := 3;
end;
```